# DB Error: no such field "created_date"

Tags: contacts, relationships

When I try to add or edit an "Employee of" Relationship, I get a "no such field" error, although this field exists in the database. Any ideas how to proceed?

CiviCRM 5.48.2; MySQL:5; PHP 7.4

From error log

````
    [message] => DB Error: no such field
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => INSERT INTO `civicrm_relationship` (`contact_id_a` , `contact_id_b` , `relationship_type_id` , `start_date` , `end_date` , `is_active` , `description` , `is_permission_a_b` , `is_permission_b_a` ) VALUES ( 55680 ,  1377 ,  4 ,  NULL ,  NULL ,  1 , '' ,  0 ,  0 )  [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'created_date' in 'field list']
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => INSERT INTO `civicrm_relationship` (`contact_id_a` , `contact_id_b` , `relationship_type_id` , `start_date` , `end_date` , `is_active` , `description` , `is_permission_a_b` , `is_permission_b_a` ) VALUES ( 55680 ,  1377 ,  4 ,  NULL ,  NULL ,  1 , '' ,  0 ,  0 )  [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'created_date' in 'field list']
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such field" code=-19 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="INSERT INTO `civicrm_relationship` (`contact_id_a` , `contact_id_b` , `relationship_type_id` , `start_date` , `end_date` , `is_active` , `description` , `is_permission_a_b` , `is_permission_b_a` ) VALUES ( 55680 ,  1377 ,  4 ,  NULL ,  NULL ,  1 , '' ,  0 ,  0 )  [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'created_date' in 'field list']"]
)```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have logging turned on (admin - system settings - misc)? If so then the log table is probably out of sync. Check log_civicrm_relationship to see if it has the field. If it doesn't have the field, try admin - system settings - clear cache and also rebuilding triggers: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/troubleshooting/#trigger-rebuild

`https://example.org/civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1&triggerRebuild=1`

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved the problem.